# How is other content besides views handled with PortableAreas from the MVCContrib library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have seen blog entries like [ASP.Net MVC Portable Areas - Part 2](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/02/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-part-2.aspx) that indicate that the build action for views must be set to **Embedded Resource**.

What about other content such as images and CSS? Should they be set to **Embedded Resource** as well? Will the PortableArea ViewEngine pull that content out as well?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

As long as your images/css/scripts are marked as Embedded Resources and follow the following convention:

```
> Areas
    > AreaName
        > Content
            > Styles
               Site.css
            > Images
               myImage.jpg
            > Scripts
               site.js
```

You get it for free!  The routes generated to the embedded resources are:

```
~/AreaName/Styles/Site.css
~/AreaName/Images/myImage.jpg
~/AreaName/Scripts/site.js
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with master pages though. <%@ Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Core/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %> fails when trying with a portable area 'Core'

Comment: @Sam are you trying to embed the master page itself?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to embed it and reference from another project